# Arrays.asList() implementation in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In Arrays.java file. The method asList is defined as below.

```
 @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... arr) {
        return new ArrayList<>(arr);
    }
```

Here the ArrayList constructor is invoked with an Array.(arr), new ArrayList(arr).
But there is no constructor in ArrayList class which accepts Array as argument.Array class is in Collections FrameWork but doesn't implement  Collection interface.
The constructors in ArrayList are

```
ArrayList()

ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)

ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

can someone explain what is happening there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It uses the constructor `ArrayList(E[] array)` of the private static class `ArrayList<E>`, which is present in the `Arrays.java` file.

Comment: ...and it was located immediately after the asList method!!! Just for the history